# Is there a keyboard shortcut to start a screensaver?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, screensaver

For example, like I can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock my computer, can I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+(*something*) to start my screensaver? I'd like it to be just like if it starts automatically, where it will show lock screen on resume, etc.

Comment: As far as I can remember, each screensaver has executable module. Did you try to start it manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

- A simple shortcut – as Peter Maxwell suggested – will do. To lock the workstation on resume, just make the shortcut point to the following:

  ```
  cmd /c start /wait scrnsave.scr /s && rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation
  ```

  Note that you cannot specify the <kbd>Win</kbd> key as part of the keyboard shortcut. Windows only allows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> as modifier.

  This has also the drawback of locking the workstation after the screensaver has *ended*, which allows a short glimpse at the desktop.
- Download [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), execute `nircmd.exe` inside the archive and click `Copy To Windows Directory`.

  Now, create a shortcut pointing to the following:

  ```
  cmd /c nircmd lockws && nircmd cmdwait 1000 screensaver
  ```

  This will start the screensaver 1000 ms *after* the screen has been locked, which is more secure.

  NirCmd will always launch the default screensaver (which may or may not be what you want).
- If you insist in the <kbd>Win</kbd> key for the keyboard shortcut, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

  1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version.
  2. Save one of the following scripts as `screensaver.ahk`, using your favorite text editor:

     ```
     #s::
         RunWait, scrnsave.scr /s
         Run, rundll32 user32.dll`,LockWorkStation
     return
     ```

     ```
     #s::
         Run, nircmd lockws
         Run, nircmd cmdwait 1000 screensaver
     return
     ```
  3. Double-click the file to run the script.
  4. (optional) Copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.

  Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (`#` represents the <kbd>Win</kbd> key) will have the same effect as executing the corresponding shortcut from the previous items.

Answer (score 7):

Create a shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr` then assign a shortcut key in **Properties**.

scrnsave.scr is a black screensaver, choose another scr file for the screensaver you wish to load.

[Source of information](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-a-Screensaver-Keyboard-Shortcut-for-/)

Comment: That just gives me a black screen that doesn't lock my computer. Also, no key shortcuts will work on it (even though they show up under properties). My screensaver is the text one that shows the time and spins.

Comment: Just created a shortcut to my Plane9.scr file (great screensaver) and assigned Ctrl+Alt+S to it. Still works like a charm in Win 10.

Answer (score 1):

There's a LifeHacker article titled [*PushMonitOff Links Hot Key Combo to Monitor Power Switch*](http://lifehacker.com/5164692/pushmonitoff-links-hot-key-combo-to-monitor-power-switch) about a tiny app which will turn your monitor off via a configurable hot key combination. As mentioned in the article, the app can be downloaded from [here](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#PushMonitOff).

Alternatively, you could use the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) utility with a simple script to do what you want. Here's the one I currently use which just turns the monitor off (it doesn't lock the computer because I've commented-out the second line that would have done that):

```
^#l:: ; ctrl+winkey+l
;SendInput #l ; lock the computer (not currently enabled)
Sleep 1000 ;  Give user a chance to release keys (in case their release would wake up the monitor again)
SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager
; 0x112 is WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF170 is SC_MONITORPOWER
; Note for the above: Use -1 in place of 2 to turn the monitor on.
; Use 1 in place of 2 to activate the monitor's low-power mode.
return
```